# How to make a popup form appear after clicking an 'empty' slot on a weekly calendar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar

I am trying to create a calendar in which you can switch between month and week view. I don't think it will be hard to create the grid for the calendar, but I want to have a popup that appears when I click a slot on the calendar. Just like in Google Calendar, when you click a slot, a pop-up appears and you can edit your new event. I want to do something like that where the event will be created and then stored in the backend SQL file that I have.

This is the code I have currently:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Week View</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Sunday</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6:00 am</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
 
 <tr>
    <td>7:00 am</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>8:00 am</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
   <tr>
    <td>9:00 am</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>10:00 am</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>11:00 am</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>12:00 pm</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>1:00 pm</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>2:00 pm</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>3:00 pm</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>4:00 pm</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>5:00 pm</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>6:00 pm</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>7:00 pm</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>8:00 pm</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>9:00 pm</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>10:00 pm</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>11:00 pm</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>12:00 am</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>1:00 am</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>2:00 am</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>3:00 am</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>4:00 am</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>5:00 am</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

and this basically shows this
[basic time schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mtLz.png)

I want to make the empty slots like some kind of button and that, when clicked, will open up a popup that will give me the option to choose the time of the event I want to place. After 'saving' this event, I want to send this info to my SQL database and then this block will then be disabled. I have already looked into existing websites that provide code for calendars, but I prefer to do it on my own (please don't send me back to fullcalendar). How do I make these empty slots, like buttons, that will open up a popupform?

Let me know if there is anything you want me to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could place a `<div>` in each `<td>` and assign 'onclick' method to run JS function.
In your JS function, use createElement to create a popup `<div>` and appendChild it to `body`. Then you will see the popup.

Comment: Do you mean for each?